# Deploy REST API with dependencies

Tags: rest, api, machine-learning

I want to deploy a trained machine learning model as a REST API. The API would take a file and first decompose it into features. The problem is that this step depends on other libraries (e.g., [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)). The API would then query the model with the features from the previous step.

Theoretically I can spin up a virtual machine in the cloud, install all the dependencies there, and point the end point to that VM. But this won't scale if we have concurrent requests.

Ideally I'd love to put everything in a API gateway and leverage serverless paradigm so I don't have to worry about scalability.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to decompose your model into different steps. From your question I see preprocessing and model inference steps.
Your preprocessing includes dependencies such as a FFTW.
You didn't specify what kind of model do you have, but I assume that it also requires some sort of environment and/or dependencies.

Having said that, what do you need to do is to implement 2 services for each step.
It's better pack them into docker images in order to keep each container isolated and you will be able to easily deploy them.

Scalability on a docker lever could be achieved by deployment into cloud providers and docker orchestration with AWS ECS or Kubernetes.

There is an open-source project [hydro-serving](https://github.com/Hydrospheredata/hydro-serving) that could help you with this task.

In this case you just need to focus on the models themselves. `hydro-serving` takes care of the infrastructure.

If preprocessing stage is implemented as Python script --  we can deploy it with all deps from `requirements.txt` in individual containers. 
The same is also true for the model -- it has have out-of-box of Tensorflow and Spark models.
Otherwise it's easy to adapt existing mechanism to satisfy your requirements (other language/toolkit)

Then, assuming that you already have a `hydro-serving` instance somewhere, you upload your steps with `hs upload --host $HOST --port $PORT`
and compose an application pipeline with your models.
You can access your application via HTTP api, GRPC api or Kafka topic.

It would be great if you'd specify what the files you are trying to send to REST API.
Possibly you will need to encode them somehow, in order to send them through REST API. On the other hand you could just send them as-is via GRPC api.

Disclosure: I'm a developer of [hydro-serving](https://github.com/Hydrospheredata/hydro-serving)